# Lebesgue Outer Measure Null Set Proof

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

I am trying to solve the following proof: Let $||$ be the Lebesgue outer measure. Show that if $|B|=0$ then $|A\cup B|=|A|$. If I consider $B=\{x_1,x_2,....\}$ this is easy enough. Consider an arbitrary open covering of $A \subset \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} I_i$. Let us consider the open covering for $B\subset\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}(x_n-\frac{\epsilon}{2^n},x_n+\frac{\epsilon}{2^n})$. Then
Consider the open covering of $A\cup B\subset \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigg\{ I_n\cup (x_n-\frac{\epsilon}{2^n},x_n+\frac{\epsilon}{2^n})\bigg\}$. Then we get

$$|A\cup B|\le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}l(I_n)+\epsilon\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}l(I_n)+2\epsilon.$$

Since the covering for A was arbitrary:

$$|A\cup B|\le |A|+2\epsilon.$$

Letting $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$

$$|A\cup B|\le |A|.$$ The reverse inequality holds by monotonicity. I can't think of another set $B$ that would have measure zero that is not a countable set of singletons. If there is can anyone provide an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [middle thirds set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) of Cantor, i.e. the set of all numbers in the interval $[0,1]$ whose ternary expansion does not contain the digit $1$, is an uncountable set of Lebesgue measure zero.

Comment: How would I generalize this proof? Since $B$ has a measure of zero then I should be able to find a covering of length $\epsilon$. Then the same argument as above would work with the interval of the singletons replaced with this new interval. Would this be an ok generalization to he proof?

Comment: what do you mean by "an interval of the singletons"? Of course, uncountable sets may be covered by countable collections of intervals.

Comment: In the proof above I used $(x_n-\frac{\epsilon}{2^n},x_n+\frac{\epsilon}{2^n})$ as a covering for $B$. Since you have provided an example of a null set that is not countable, I figure since $B$ is of measure zero there must be a covering that has measure $\epsilon$ to replace the one provided for the countable case.

Comment: Yes, there is such a covering, and it is not hard to construct one once you realize how the Cantor set is constructed.